# How do I pick a correct xDebug library?

Tags: xdebug

I have the following PHP: `php -v` output.

```
PHP 7.1.12 (cli) (built: Nov 23 2017 04:34:08) ( ZTS MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015) x86 )
```

How do I pickup a correct [xDebug](https://xdebug.org/download.php) library for this package?

It normally says, `Failed loading php_xdebug-*.dll` for most of the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Xdebug Wizard page -- it will tell you just that: https://xdebug.org/wizard.php

- Just paste there either `php -i` output (grabbed from terminal/console) or `phpinfo()` output grabbed via browser (just text -- no HTML).
- In return it will tell what's your PHP build is, what xdebug build you should download and how to install it.

NOTE: It will offer you the very last version, which is 2.6.0beta1 at the moment. I suggest sticking to latest stable version, which is 2.5.5 -- for that just alter the URL a bit.

---

Based on your PHP info you most likely will need the link labelled `PHP 7.1 VC14 TS (32 bit)` in [downloads page](https://xdebug.org/download.php): this would be [php_xdebug-2.5.5-7.1-vc14.dll](https://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.5.5-7.1-vc14.dll) as it stands for today.

Comment: It suggested php_xdebug-2.6.0beta1-7.1-vc14.dll, and worked well. Thank you. Choosing stable version.